# I can't inspect element of the Oracle GUI in Chrome

Tags: oracle, google-chrome, user-interface

First time on the website.

I am testing an Oracle GUI with Selenium on Chrome and I need to inspect element. When pressing F12 I get the error message 'Operation is not allowed'. Before the Upgrade I had to clear Cache and then this function was working fine. Now I am blocked.

It is NOT working on IE, but it is working on FireFox.

N/A

Comment: What does this have to do with oracle?

Comment: Before upgrade of what?  Oracle? Selenium?

Comment: The 'inspect element' function does not work for the Oracle GUI in the Chrome browser. For other websites it works fine.

Comment: Upgrade of Oracle software